# Unix command to search with a string of 6 numbers for any 3 matching numbers per line

Tags: text-processing

Does anyone know of a UNIX command or series of commands to list lines that contains 3 matching numbers to a search with 6 numbers? For example, searching with 38 39 40 41 42 43 I would like to see combinations like 38 40 43 or 39 41 42 listed per line. Thanks.

Comment: Do you want only lines where these numbers are separated only by a space, and do these numbers need to be distinct and/or in the order you typed them? So what about `38 38 40` or `38 43 40`?

Comment: Unix or UNIX. Unix is the generic name for e.g. BSD, System-V, Gnu, etc. UNIX is a brand name.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have a file named `file` that contains lines with mutually different whitespace-separated numbers, and you have a set of 6 numbers - e.g. 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43 - that you want to search for in combinations of three, such that lines that consecutively contain three of these numbers in random order are listed as a result of the search, you could use:

```
grep -P  '((^|\s+)(38|39|40|41|42|43)(?=($|\s))){3}' file
```

which uses grep with a Perl regular expression (PCRE).